# How does the Zhang Suen Thinning Algorithm achieve thinning of an image?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I have the Zhang Suen algorithm properly implemented in MATLAB and its producing a fine output but I am lacking understanding of how does it achieve thinning?

I am attaching here the links that maybe of help in understanding my problem.

A document discussing the implementation of various image thinning techniques

- http://www.iasj.net/iasj?func=fulltext&aId=34184

Research paper of Zhang + Suen:

- http://www-prima.inrialpes.fr/perso/Tran/Draft/gateway.cfm.pdf

Comment: You've forgotten to actually ask a question. A question that is shorter to answer than by completely reproducing the papers you cite.

Answer (score 1):

An explanation about various 'thinning' methods in automatic image procession as used by ImageMagick can be found here:

- **[Thinning *(Subtracting Pixels from a Shape)*](http://www.imagemagick.com/Usage/morphology/#thinning_skeleton)**

This section of the ImageMagick documentation provides quite a few examples. 
To *really* understand it though, you should start reading up about 'Morphology' and 'Kernels' in ImageMagick (at the top of the same page):

- **[Morphology Introduction](http://www.imagemagick.com/Usage/morphology/#intro)**

---

<sub>Note, that I have not heard about the 'Zhang Suen' thinning algorithm before. ImageMagick also does ***not*** support it.</sub>

Comment: I understand thinning as far as the theory is concerned but i do not understand how is this specific algorithm achieving thinning.

Comment: Sorry. Then I cannot be of any further help for now. I do not have the time to study these papers you linked to in order to try and understand this algorithm.